# arrow function property prototype as undefined

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Below I have created two functions f1 as a normal function and f2 as an arrow function, out of which the arrow function could not be instantiated with new keyword with error as below:

```
var f1 = () => { console.log('f1') }
// undefined
var b = new f1();
// Uncaught TypeError: f1 is not a constructor
```

while,

```
function f2() { console.log('f2') }
// undefined
var c = new f2();
// f2
// undefined
```

both f1 and f2 are of type function as:

```
typeof f1
// "function"
typeof f2
// "function"
```

but the normal function f1 has a **prototype** property having **constructor** while the function f2 which is an arrow function does not have it

```
f2.prototype.constructor
// ƒ f2() { console.log('f2') }
f1.prototype
// undefined
```

Is this a normal behavior of arrow functions as they don't contain prototype property or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "Is this a normal behavior of arrow functions"? Yes.